Merge [slate-react] and [react-slate]
I propose to merge slate-react into react-slate.
Why?

Both tags existing is clearly due to people writing one word before the other, and they're obviously meant to be the same tag
The react community has chosen to format their tags with the language name followed by the library name, so react-slate should be the one staying.


Definitely duplicate tags, they've been merged and synonymised to conform with the other [react-*] tags:
updating post history, 10 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 9 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 9 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'slate-react': [slate-react] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 21
tag remapping of [react-slate] and [slate-react] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym slate-react -> react-slate was approved!

